# Showing the number of converging sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the following set is a finite union of convergent sequences:

$$A=\frac{n-1}{n}\cos\frac{2\pi n}{3}, n\in \Bbb N$$

Can ease help me with this question? I know that cosine gets values $-1/2, 1$, but I do not know how to write that rigourously. It is obvious that the set has infimum and supremum, but I do not know how to show that the converging sequences are finite

Thanks!

Comment: Look at how $\cos \frac{2\pi n}{3}$ behaves.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know it gets values $-1/2$ and $1$, but i dont know hot to write that rigourously

Comment: Partition $\mathbb{N}$ into $A$ and $B$, where $A = \bigl\{ n : \cos \frac{2\pi n}{3} = 1\bigr\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How about the fraction part? Should I write that its limit is equal to 1? Sorry if it seems stupid, but I do not know how to write this

Comment: You have two sequences, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$. You look at the set $\{ x_n \cdot y_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. You want to partition that into finitely many parts, each of which is the underlying set of a convergent sequence. If both, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ have only finitely many accumulation points (cluster points), you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
A_{3p}&=\frac{3p-1}{3p}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi \times 3p}{3}\right)=\frac{3p-1}{3p}, \quad p\in \Bbb N-\{0\}
\\\\
A_{3p+1}&=\frac{3p}{3p+1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi \times (3p+1)}{3}\right)=\frac{3p}{3p+1}\:\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right), \quad p\in \Bbb N,
\\\\
A_{3p+2}&=\frac{3p+1}{3p+2}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi \times (3p+2)}{3}\right)=\frac{3p+1}{3p+2}\:\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right), \quad p\in \Bbb N.
\end{align}
$$